# How to unset post params from header/ Zend_Registry

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

Is it possible to remove or to unset post variables from header or

```
 Zend_Registry::get('request')
```

i've tried to make a redirection, it works on Chrome,

```
  header("Location: /my_pages/page");
   exit(1);
```

... but not on Firefox :

> ```
>   The page isn't redirecting properly
>
>    Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for 
>    this address in a way that will never complete
> ```

Comment: have you tried unset($_POST)?

Comment: yes but nothing changes !

Comment: Please post more code so we can have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this inside my head tags of the page i want a single reload on:

```
   <?php
    if (!isset($_GET['stop-reload'])) {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content= "0;URL=?stop-reload=yes" />';
    }
    ?>
```

the value "mc" can be set to whatever you want, but both must match in the 2 lines. and the "=test" can be "=anythingyouwant" it just needs a value to stop the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is probably seeing what Firefox is probably ignoring:

You keep running header() on each page load, which is causing a loop.

You should at least check with an if() , if the variable(s) you wish to unset still exist, before doing header().

```
if (isset($_POST["myVar"])) {
 header("Location: /my_pages/page");
 exit(1);
}
```

But did you try first just using plain unset(), without any header() and stuff ?

```
unset($_POST['myVars']);
unset($_REQUEST['myVars']);
```

Comment: yes i've cleared a my vars ! but nothing changes, whene the JS script try to reload the page, i have this notification box

Comment: @Rastaking The Js Script? What Js Script?

Comment: in my page, i have a button that works with JS/Ajax, it create a new record on the data base and add it to the session then it reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use redirector as specified below
 $this->_helper->redirector('action_name','controller_name');